# Systematically track rows being grouped by in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a huge table with > 1M rows, and it looks like:

| Row | Date | Condition | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20210101 | Shipment | 100 |
| 2 | 20210101 | Call | 200 |
| 3 | 20210102 | Examination | 500 |
| 4 | 20210102 | Examination | 5 |
| 5 | 20210103 | Shipment | 100 |

In most cases, there is only one single row, when I consider both Date and Condition (such as row 1, 2, 5). However, I do find few situations, like row 3 and 4, where Date and Condition are exactly the same; yet there are more than one row showed up.

I would like to find these rows so that further analysis can be done.

I could use group by and get averages/mediums for Value, considering Date and Condition.

```
select Date, Condition, Max(value) from test_table
group by Date, Condition
```

However how do I know which rows (such as 3 and 4) actually got averaged? Maybe I could ask this question in a better way but am relatively new to sql and would appreciate your advice here. Thank you.

Comment: What happens if you change the `GROUP BY` to `GROUP BY DATE, TRIM(CONDITION)`? Also, what are the data types of `DATE` and `CONDITION`?

Comment: Hi @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica thank you for your comment. I am not sure how to change it to trim... Added my current code to the question, but adding trim will end up in syntax error. To answer your question - Date is int and Condition is char

Comment: Try changing your statement to  `SELECT DATE, TRIM(CONDITION) FROM test_table GROUP BY DATE, TRIM(CONDITION)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the duplicate rows by using a window function to compute the "group size". For example:

```
select *
from (
  select *,
    count(*) over(partition by date, condit) as group_size
  from t
) x
where group_size > 1
```

Result:

```
 id  date        condit       value  group_size 
 --- ----------- ------------ ------ ---------- 
 3   2021-01-02  Examination  500    2          
 4   2021-01-02  Examination  5      2
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cAPDfQpPjSpRkEaMXiKk7R/0).

Comment: Thank you this works! How should I under stand this line please? count(*) over(partition by date, condit) as group_size

Comment: @Helene That is typically known as a "window function". The `SUM()` happens over a subset of the rows specified by `PARTITION BY`. See details at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/tutorial-window.html